# BigQuery Java API ".jobs().insert()" is partially populating the destination table

Tags: google-bigquery

I am using BigQuery Java API for populating the data from one table into another, following is the code which i am using

```
Job insertJob = new Job();
    JobConfiguration insertJobConfig = new JobConfiguration();

    TableReference destinationTable = new TableReference();
    destinationTable.setProjectId(projectId);
    destinationTable.setDatasetId(datasetId);
    destinationTable.setTableId(destinationBQTable);

    JobConfigurationQuery queryConfig = new JobConfigurationQuery();
    queryConfig.setQuery("select * from " + datasetId + Constant.PERIOD +sourceBQTable);
    queryConfig.setDestinationTable(destinationTable);
    queryConfig.setWriteDisposition("WRITE_TRUNCATE");
    queryConfig.setPriority("BATCH");
    insertJob.setConfiguration(insertJobConfig.setQuery(queryConfig));

    Bigquery.Jobs.Insert request = bigqueryService.jobs().insert(projectId, insertJob);
    Job response = request.execute();
    return response.getJobReference().getJobId();
```

I am facing one intermittent issue where my destination table is not populating fully for e.g., source table has 189,856 rows but destination table has only 41,721 rows. I am not seeing any error in the logs.

Has anyone experienced this before with BigQuery - a query appearing to run successfully but if a destination/reference table was specified the results were not fully populated?

**Note**: we again faced this problem on July 21 and this time I also logged the Job Id which is: job_8zt5hHdsPhizl2RFZ9g57EMcgy0

Thanks,
Aman

Comment: please add a jobId so Google engineers can check

Comment: I don't have the Job Id, we log JobId only when we get some error in logs

Comment: @Pentium10 we again faced this problem on July 21, 2017 and this time I also logged the Job Id which is: job_8zt5hHdsPhizl2RFZ9g57EMcgy0